# Unable to install a package on Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-install, next.js

I've been trying to install styled-components on Next JS by entering `npm install --save styled-components` but it keeps giving me this error...

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ry.npmjs.org/fork-ts-'
```

Please can anyone help me out?

Comment: Could you explain a little more

Comment: There's really not much to explain. I created a new NextJS project, tried to install styled components dependency on it but it threw the error. But don't worry, the question has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clean the `npm` cache running the following command:

`npm cache clean --force`